# Why are external stylesheet styles overriding internal and inline styles?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm working in a site that has a global stylesheet that (badly, IMO) sets styles on element types. I'm building some ASP.NET user controls for various pages and I keep running into issues where my internal and inline styles are overridden by the styles in the global stylesheet. I'm using Firefox. For example, I just added a control with a table in it. While developing, I have the style declared internally in the user control (so it's not in the page head). The external global.css stylesheet has declared:

```
div#copy table {
  width: auto;
}
```

My internal declaration has:

```
table.MMPointBalance {
  border: 0 none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

width:200px is being overridden to auto by the external stylesheet. <strike>In other similar cases, I've been having inline declarations on Telerik controls being overidden by some very genearal global.css styles.</strike> (false statement). Internal and inline are supposed to take priority. I would think the selector of the inline style above would also be more specific than the global. Why isn't it applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) for CSS and [Priority](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/) are tricky to handle sometimes, in this case:

This selector is much more specific because it is selecting a parent specific div with `id` and then his table child.

> div#copy table

This is just setting a table with class:

> table.MMPointBalance

Also if you have `!important` declarations on the global.css you have to handle that with the same or more specific `!important`

Comment: Nice links and specific terminology.

Comment: You're correct. So I updated my internal selector to div#copy table.MMPointBalance. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help you save those links for next doubts about the theme.

Comment: Specificity was the key word for sure @DaniP! Helping me 10 years later. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The rule using div#copy takes precedence because using the ID there makes the overall rule more specific.  You can either alter one of the rules, or use !important

> In other similar cases, I've been having inline declarations on Telerik controls being overidden by some very genearal global.css styles.

Inline styles (using the style attribute) will only be overridden by external styles if !important is used.

Comment: unless you use `!important`

Comment: I don't think that's accurate.  The following example yields blue text:  <style>
.a { color: red !important; }
</style>
<span style="color:blue;">foo</span>

Comment: It would. You haven't given `class="a"` to the `span`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/24Yz8/)

Comment: You're right. I was misremembering. The styles referenced by Telerik were being overridden, probably due to specificity. The inline style I was thinking of was simply being ignored, not overridden, and that was due to another issue. Thanks!